# Python / Linux to Windows / calling external module with subprocess

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

I need to adapt a python code from linux to windows.

In the linux version, a python file "extract_backup.py" is called with this line :

```
script_manager = Popen(['python', path_to_script], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
```

Unfortunately I can't load external modules like Pandas in the extract_backup.py (just regular ones like os, zipfile, sys...) because I am running the main python within an virtual environement, and obviously subprocess will use my default python path (which is different)

Is there a way to resolve that or should I abandonned the subprocess calling ?

Comment: Why are you calling Python as a subprocess of itself in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sys.executable` to find the python interpreter currently in use.

```
import subprocess
import sys
script_manager = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, path_to_script], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE)
```

Comment: (Failing that, you could always check if a file name python or something exists under one of the folders of `sys.path`.)